# Sortable - span keeps duplicating on portlet move

Tags: jquery, icons, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a portlet that adds this to the element upon updating (moving the portlet), but for some reason the `ui-icon-pencil` element keeps duplicating on every move.

How do I stop this happening?

Here's what I am adding to the portlet:

```
$(".portlet").addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all")
        .find(".portlet-header")
        .addClass("ui-widget-header ui-corner-all")
        .prepend("<span style='float:right; margin-right: 17px;' class='ui-icon ui-icon-pencil portlet-edit'></span><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick portlet-toggle'></span>");
```

Event handler:

function UpdateUI() {
    $(".column").sortable({
        connectWith: ".column",
        handle: ".portlet-header",
        cancel: ".portlet-toggle",
        placeholder: "portlet-placeholder ui-corner-all",

```
    // When Story status changed.
    receive: function (event, ui) {
        var sourceList = ui.sender; // Story origin
        var targetList = $(this); // Story destination
        var itemID = $(ui.item).attr("id"); // UserStoryID
        UpdateStoryStatus(itemID, sourceList, targetList);
    },

    // On portlet moved.
    update: function (event, ui) {
        UpdateStoryOrder();
    }
});

$('input:checkbox').change(
function () {
    var isChecked;
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) { isChecked = true; }
    else { isChecked = false; }
    var type = $(this).attr('id');
    var reqID = $(this).closest('.req').attr('id');
    UpdateReqStatus(reqID, type, isChecked);
});

$(".portlet").addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all")
        .find(".portlet-header")
        .addClass("ui-widget-header ui-corner-all")
        .prepend("<img style='float:right; margin-right: 17px;' class='ui-icon ui-icon-pencil portlet-edit'></img><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick portlet-toggle'></span>");

$(".portlet-edit").click(function () {
    var icon = $(this);
    alert("LOL");
});

$(".portlet-toggle").click(function () {
    var icon = $(this);
    icon.toggleClass("ui-icon-minusthick ui-icon-plusthick");
    icon.closest(".portlet").find(".portlet-content").toggle();
});
```

}

Comment: where is the event handler?

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle for this

Comment: @PranavCBalan The event handler is just a UpdateUI() function that gets called when moving the element.

Comment: @Bodzilla: share the code

Comment: @PranavCBalan updated code above to include event handler.

Comment: @Bodzilla Use a boolean variable to prepend based on that update it when prepended and check the value on next time